# Processing выдаёт ошибку "JSONArray[2] not found

Tags: json, processing

Вопрос в заголовке.

```
for (int i = 0; i  <= UserData.size(); i++) {
        if(i >= UserData.size()){
      JSONObject NamePass = UserData.getJSONObject(i++); //Ошибка в этой строчке.
```

Тот самый JSON файл.

```
[
  [{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName1212121"
  }]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего надо так:

```
for (int i = 0; i  < UserData.size(); i++) {
```

Потому что в ином случае (при условии `i  <= UserData.size();`) происходит три итерации и на третьей итерации будет попытка взять элемент с индексом 2, которого нет